# How to authorize API Connections in Azure as different user using powershell when single sign on

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication

We use Azure Logic Apps that are deployed from DEV to TEST to PROD using powershell scripts. Thoe Logic Apps use API connections.

For certain API connections we want to use a different Service User instead of my personal account. So if a Logic App sends an E-Mail it should send it as Service User and not myself. The special thing about API connections is, that Azure forces you to re-authenticate them after deployment by powershell script. So after each deployment you need to re-authorize API connections.

I successfully managed to authenticate using powershell script with the sample mentioned here: https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppConnectionAuth

However, it will always somehow authorize me on with my Windows account. I am not able to log in as someone else. When the Azure Logon Window appears and I enter the service users name, but it will then not ask me for the passwort, it will authorize the connection with my personal user right after entering a username.

How can I use Azure powershell commands to perform connection authorization as a different user?

I was hoping someone could point me into a better direction (google keywords, etc.) on how to authorize API connection as a different user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your question is about authorizing API connections with different user account or service accounts. The behavior you specified above is specifically for office 365 connection. Authorization mechanism differs in different set of connectors.

However, for using service accounts to authorize Office 365 API connections, we need to make sure that browser cache doesn't use the Windows/Azure logon credentials automatically.
You can clear the browser cache and do the authorization from a private browser.
If that doesn't help you, there is a hack that's explained in this blog.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure/using-service-account-for-office-365-outlook-connector/ba-p/1978513

Let me know if you have any questions.

Haris

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing the link to this hack. Not part of the powershell script anymore, but at least I can do it "manually"